# iron-data-table Is not loading data

Tags: polymer

```html
<iron-ajax
    auto
    url="http://127.0.0.1:8081/src/users.json"
    handle-as="json"
    last-response="{{users}}"
    debounce-duration="300"></iron-ajax>

      <iron-data-table items="[[users]]">

        <data-table-column name="First Name">
          <template>[[item.name.title]]</template>
        </data-table-column>
        <data-table-column name="Last Name">
          <template>[[item.name.last]]</template>
        </data-table-column>
        <data-table-column name="Email">
          <template>[[item.name.first]]</template>
        </data-table-column>
      </iron-data-table>
```

My JSON:

```
[
  {"name": {
    "title": "miss",
    "first": "donna",
    "last": "davis"
  }},
  {"name": {
    "title": "mr",
    "first": "samuel",
    "last": "kelley"
  }},
  {"name": {
    "title": "ms",
    "first": "katie",
    "last": "butler"
  }}
]
```

This is giving the following error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'columns' of undefined"
>   "iron-data-table.html:849 Uncaught TypeError: dataSource is not a function"

Comment: Which version of polymer are you using? It looks like this component used version `1.2.4` and so might be incompatible with the latest version of polymer if that's what you are using

Comment: Used all latest components  and trying with polymer 2
I am not installing the component but downloading them and putting them inside the bower folder.

Comment: It seems like polymer 2 is not compatible iron-data-table. The author is not maintaining that component anymore, according to his github (https://github.com/Saulis/iron-data-table) and recommends using vaadin-grid instead